# How to use smartphone IMU in ROS?

Tags: slam, imu, android, ros-noetic

I would like to get the IMU sensors (accelerometer and gyroscope) on my android smartphone to be usable in ROS running on my laptop so I can use it with SLAM.

What would be the best way to go about this?

I suppose I would have to write an Android app in Java which records the imu data and somehow publishes it as a ROS topic.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There was a recent thread on the ROS Discourse about a possible student project to develop this. The project didn't get started unfortunately, but still there are a lot of relevant references in that thread, see [here](https://discourse.ros.org/t/project-proposal-mobile-app-for-publishing-sensor-data-ar-pose-and-depth/32497).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the plan down - its the details of making it happen :-) You can also just send the raw data off the phone and then publish it via ROS on the main computer (if the phone isn't the main computer) so that you don't need to pull ROS onto the phone. If you already have ROS on the phone, then that should be easy-peasy!